# Using find and sed to rename several subfolders

Tags: find, regex, zsh, sed, escape-characters

What I am trying to do is rename folders that are anywhere in the current tree, not neccessarily directly in the working directory. What I need to do is:

- "A 1" becomes "A 01"
- "A 2" becomes "A 02"
- "A 09" is ignored

I ended up with this:

`find . -type d -regex '.*A [0-9]$' -execdir mv "{}" "$(echo '{}' | sed 's_[0-9]_0&_')" \;`

In order to test this I reduced the complexity a bit:

`find . -type d -regex '.*A [0-9]$' -execdir echo "$(echo '{}' | sed 's_[0-9]_0&_')" \;`

`find` lists all folders I want but the pattern in `sed` does not seem to find a match in the folder names. It works if it is executed on its own, so I guess there is a problem with characters that need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update:* Added a version which can handle any/all valid filename characters, except for `\x01`, which is used as sed's delimiter....   I have used `A.*` as the pattern in the *updated* examples, because I was testing for `A"'`. Of course, just change to whatever you need.

```
findx="\(.*/\)\(A.* \)\([0-9]\)$"
replx="&\x00\1\20\3\x00"; I=$'\x01'
find . -depth -type d -regex "$findx" | 
  sed -n "s$I$findx$I$replx$I p" |
    tr -d '\n' | 
      xargs --verbose -0n2 mv
```

---

Here is an example, using `perl` instead of `sed`.
Note that *perl's* regualar expressions `PCRE` are not entirely the same as *posix-extended* `ERE` as used by `find` in this example. They do, however, share enough in common that the same regex pattern can be used in this case.

```
export findx='(.*/)(A.* )([0-9])$'
find . -depth -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "$findx" |
  perl -l000pe 's/$ENV{'findx'}/$_\000$1${2}0$3/' |
    xargs --verbose -0n2 mv
```

---

These next versions cannot handle single-quotes `'` in filenames.

Using standard regex patterns

```
regex='\(.*/\)\(A \)\([0-9]\)$'
find . -depth -type d -regex "$regex" |
  sed -n "s|$regex|'&' '\1\20\3'|p" |
    xargs --verbose -n2 mv
```

To use extended regex paterns

```
regex='(.*/)(A )([0-9])$'
find . -depth -regextype posix-extended -type d -regex "$regex" |
  sed -nr "s|$regex|'&' '\1\20\3'|p" |
    xargs --verbose -n2 mv
```

The `-depth` option is needed so that *more deeply* nested directories are renamed before any parent directory is renamed.

Note that the script does not test if a directory already exists with the same name as the new intended name.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works well except in a case where a ' (single quote) character is in the name. Any idea how to tell sed or xargs to escape critical characters?
You don't happen to spot the error in my command using -execdir? Using xargs like you did looks much easier and clearer, but I would like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Your regex was basically on track, but when you start needing to echo into an echo, I find there is often another way by using a straightt pipe-line.  I have added a version which caters for  single *and/or* double quotes and any other valid character other than `\x01`, which is used as sed's delimiter, and `\x00` which is not valid in *nix filenames.  Quoting the file paths is nott needed if you use `xargs` with the `-0, --null` option as an arg-separator.. I've added an extra `tr` step to remove the spurious `\n` which sed needs. If you use `perl` instead of `sed` you could avoid this step.

Comment: Note that `-execdir` changes the working directory to the parent directory for each path being processed. This means that you do not need to use fully-qualified paths. *But*, on its own, it *does not* produce a `-depth` listing with deeper level directories before their parents. If you have `/abc/A 1/B 2/` and `/abc/A 1` is renamed first, then depending on how `find` handles its buffering, it may try to rename `/abc/A 1/B 2`, but that no longer exists! ...  so, for this situation use `-depth`.

Comment: Thanks for the great effort. 
I must say the shell is a minefield when it comes to file renaming stuff like this. Next time I will use some higher-level language... ;)